# Why is authentification failing? C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Registering page accepts usernames that are already included in database, even though I included code to prevent that:

```
string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtCustUserName.Text + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

 if (temp > 0)
{
    Response.Write("User already exists");
}
```

This is the whole code for register page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtCustUserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "INSERT into Customers (CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustProv, CustPostal, CustCountry, CustHomePhone, CustBusPhone, CustEmail, CustUserName, CustPassword) values (@custFirstName ,@custLastName ,@custAddress ,@custCity ,@custProv ,@custPostal, @custCountry ,@custHomePhone ,@custBusPhone ,@custEmail ,@custUserName ,@custPassword)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custFirstName", txtCustFirstName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custLastName", txtCustLastName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custAddress", txtCustAddress.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCity", txtCustCity.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custProv", txtCustProv.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPostal", txtCustPostal.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCountry", txtCustCountry.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custHomePhone", txtCustHomePhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custBusPhone", txtCustBusPhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custEmail", txtCustEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custUsername", txtCustUserName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPassword", txtCustPassword.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration is successful" );

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The login page marks all logins as "wrong username" even though the username and password are correct.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtUsername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery= "SELECT password FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtUsername.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

            if(password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUsername.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password is not correct");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Username is not correct");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I assume Button1_Click event handle the Submit for Registration then your doing it wrong your checking must be in the click event and not it the Page_Load.

Comment: You should NEVER EVER do this: ```string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtUsername.Text + "'";``` This opens up for SQL injection. I know this does not relate to your question, but you need to know!

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I changed it, and it still accepts duplicates.

Comment: @SteenTøttrup Thanks for the advice. Do you have a suggestion on a better way to prevent duplicates?

Comment: Can you update your question so I can view your changes?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Yup, I just updated it, thanks.

Comment: @4201 it has nothing to do with your issue, you should NEVER add parameters to your string like that, you should do it like you've done in the method, create a SqlCommand instance and ```myCommand.Parameters.Add``` instead.

Comment: Regarding the question, if you only ever want to allow one customer with a give name, you could add that constraint to the database, making that field unique. But you should also check it in your code, to avoid any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtCustUserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            conn.Close();
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Open();
                string insertQuery = "INSERT into Customers (CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustProv, CustPostal, CustCountry, CustHomePhone, CustBusPhone, CustEmail, CustUserName, CustPassword) values (@custFirstName ,@custLastName ,@custAddress ,@custCity ,@custProv ,@custPostal, @custCountry ,@custHomePhone ,@custBusPhone ,@custEmail ,@custUserName ,@custPassword)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custFirstName", txtCustFirstName.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custLastName", txtCustLastName.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custAddress", txtCustAddress.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCity", txtCustCity.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custProv", txtCustProv.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPostal", txtCustPostal.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCountry", txtCustCountry.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custHomePhone", txtCustHomePhone.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custBusPhone", txtCustBusPhone.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custEmail", txtCustEmail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custUsername", txtCustUserName.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPassword", txtCustPassword.Text);

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
                Response.Write("Registration is successful" );

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome, the database is no longer accepting duplicates, thanks a lot!

Comment: Anytime, it will be a big help to learn about ASP.NET Validators in your way. :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of temp here during debugging?:

```
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

If you have duplicate records in your table, the variable temp will never be 1.

Set CustUserName as a primary key on your Customers table to prevent duplicate entry.

Comment: Good point. I changed it to  "if (temp > 0) " but it still accepts duplicates.

Comment: And what is the value of temp?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a new programmer: how can I find out the value of temp?

Comment: Take a look at this video to get a basic idea of debugging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A